# Json Parsing in Node Js : Appending the Key: value in front of the Json

Tags: json, node.js

I have a Json which has so many lines of code. It has a time stamp that can distinguish it from other Json's. I need to take out that time stamp and append it in front of the Json itself. I do not know how to proceed.

For Json. Take any Json with time stamp.

Comment: give more details about your requirement along with JSON snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is one of your jsons

```
{"name": "test", "ts": 18928938}
```

You can simply get the ts, append to another json and then remove the ts if you don't need it.

```
var result = {};
var json1 = {"name": "test", "ts": 18928938};
result[json1.ts] = json1;
remove result[json1.ts].ts; // This is if you want to remove the original ts
```

Comment: And how do I append the overall result as "TimeStamp" +"The original Json"? And thanks for the above answer. Was simple and amazing.

Comment: I do not understand the overall result, Maybe you should show us a small example and then I can help you.